# Magento custom payment gateway Void invoice

Tags: payment-gateway

I have a question about how to using the custom payment gateway to void the invoice?

After I have create the invoice with Capture Online. (it is success to capture the payment)

Copy from magento:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/welcome_to_the_magento_user_s_guide/chapter_8

Capture Online- When the Invoice is submitted, the system will capture the payment through the third party payment gateway. You will have the ability to create a Credit Memo, or Void the Invoice.

Void - If the Order’s payment is an online method, and you have captured the payment through Magento (either automatically during Order creation, during Invoice creation, or after the Invoice has been created), the Void button will appear. Pressing this will void the payment through the third party payment gateway. Unlike Cancel, the Invoiced quantity will no longer be able to be Invoiced again.

### It means I can void the online payment after I have capture the payment or sales payment?!

But I cannot find out the void button on the order view page or invoice view page. How I can test the void function?

I am using the following code on my model

```
protected $_isGateway               = true;
protected $_canAuthorize            = true;
protected $_canCapture              = true;
protected $_canCapturePartial       = false;
protected $_canRefund               = true;
protected $_canVoid                 = true;
protected $_canVoidFlag             = true; 
protected $_canUseInternal          = false;
protected $_canUseCheckout          = true;
protected $_canCreditmemo           = true;
protected $_canUseForMultishipping  = false;

public function cancel(Varien_Object $payment){

    $this->void($payment);

    return $this;
}

public function void(Varien_Object $payment)
{
   // my code
}
```